# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named when I import file from different directory

Tags: python, python-import

mody.py file contains:

```
import sys;
sys.path.append("..");
from src import modz;
```

From /lib I run mody.py file, it works. But if I am in /main, and from main.py, import lib.mody, it will return ModuleNotFoundError: No module named src.

```
--/main
  --__init__.py
  --main.py
  --/src
    --modz.py
  --/lib
    --__init__.py
    --mody.py
```

Comment: please include full path in system path

Comment: this works fine for me

Comment: try to change 
from .src import modz;

Comment: `..` is the parent directory of wherever you were when you launched python, which might not be the same as the parent directory of the file in which that code is executed.